# Add listDefinition/Columns only to specific folder

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I would like add Columns that show data of the component but only within a specific folder. I can already show extra columns with the requested data, but now they show up everywhere (it is becoming a mess).

The reason is that I will need to add columns in multiple folders with different data. I would not want all the columns continually visible as it will result in one big mess.

Dynamically hiding the columns with JavaScript also just seems to messy and I assume that there should be a way to do this with just the customEditor.config file.

---

In response to Alvin Reyes comment on this question:

We have at this moment 3 content types, and expanding, with each their own needed data. This data is specific to that content type.

I also though about just making generic columms which would be filled in according to what is needed. The found disadvantages were:

1. the number of extra data for each content type is not the same, this would still result in empty columns (max empty would be 4).
2. It would result in not being able to add the needed translation to the right data.

Therefore, being able to hide the columns through their definition within the editor configuration file would result in allot less client sided JavaScript processing.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a wonderful feature, that could probably be implemented as an extension. But as it is, it is not possible to just specify such columns in a config file (at least not last time I checked). If you're trying to propose that SDL add this feature to Tridion, it's probably best to to so on http://ideas.sdltridion.com/.

Comment: How many columns are you adding and are they related to the types of items in a given folder? Could you share the same extended column between folders, but instead retrieve different data based on perhaps the default schema for that folder?

Comment: @AlvinReyes Yes that was one of the solutions we thought about. Side effect would be that we would still get all those columns in all the different folders and still resulting in a mess. We would only need this extension in a handful folder and adjusting everything for just those few would not be a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

Instead of extending an existing list I added a listdefinition:

```
<ext:listdefinitions>
    <view name="DashboardView">
         <control id="FilteredItemsList">
             <listdefinition idmatch="^tcm:\d+\-26-2$" url="xml with your list definition in defined" />
         </control>
    </view>
</ext:listdefinitions>
```

Here ^tcm:\d+-26-2 points to the folder 26 within all publications and therefore only apply this list definition at that specific folder.

If you want to know how to write a list definition xml, take a look at [Tridion]\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\

Comment: Clever. I imagine the next request will be a unique icon for those folders. :-)