# Data Extender columns for only components and pages

Tags: gui-extensions

I have added two more columns to the view.The problem is that,it is showing these columns for all the views.I referred [[Add listDefinition/Columns only to specific folder](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/add-listdefinition-columns-only-to-specific-folder]) and figured it can be restricted to specific items(in my case only for components and pages.Probably on click of folders and structured groups). I am not getting clarity on how to go about doing that. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So do you want the data to only be shown for components and pages? Or do you want the columns to only be shown in folders with only components and pages?

Comment: I want for only components and pages. And in the future I might have to extend for other item types.Basically components are placed in the folder and pages inside SGs currently. Hence I made a statement like that(on click of folders or SG).

Comment: I can't give you the solution but I can point you to a spot where you might find it: Take a look at the config for CME (Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\CME.config) at line 1850+ (search for "idmatch="). There you can find some examples.

Comment: I tried to add listdefinition instead of extending. Didn't really workout for me. I am lost. At the least I don't want the two extended columns to appear anywhere else other than Content Management (I don't want it in places like Administration).

Comment: @Pari -I have tried your answer but xml is loading from this path \tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\ListItems.xml not from my custom path. Is there anything else to be done? Can you share the changes from editor config?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

listdefinition idmatch="^tcm:\d+-\d+-2$ | ^tcm:\d+-\d+-4$" url="/ListDefinitions/YouListDefinitionXml.xml"

- ^tcm:\d+-\d+-2$   --> On click of Folders in the CME my newly added columns will be shown
- ^tcm:\d+-\d+-4$   --> On click of SGs in the CME my newly added columns will be shown. 
  (All the items whose parent item id matches the rule mentioned in idmatch, the columns will be shown. As components are usually in a folder and pages in SG I have used this rule)
  Hence restricting it to only components and pages. Purpose served.

  In YouListDefinitionXml.Xml define the new columns along with the once avaliable in \tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\ListItems.xml.

  @Thomas Hendrickx - thank you for your suggestion and your earlier post [Add listDefinition/Columns only to specific folder](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/add-listdefinition-columns-only-to-specific-folder%5D)