# Adding new coloumn to the CME list view - GUI Extensions

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, sites-9.1

I have added a new approval status column using GUI extensions in 9.1 but it displays everywhere. Is there anyway to restrict only to Folders and Structure Groups?

```
    <ext:lists>
      <ext:add>
        <ext:extension assignid="ColumnExtender" name="ColumnExtender" insertbefore="NamedType">
          <ext:listDefinition>
            <ext:selectornamespaces>
              <list:namespace prefix="ext" uri="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/R5/Extension" />
              </ext:selectornamespaces> 
            <ext:columns>
              <list:column xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/List" id="ApprovalStatusColumn" type="data" title="Approval Status" selector="@ext:ApprovalStatus" />
            </ext:columns>
          </ext:listDefinition>
          <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="DashboardView">
              <ext:control id="FilteredItemsList" />
            </ext:view>
          </ext:apply>
        </ext:extension>
      </ext:add>
    </ext:lists>
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not working for me in 9.1. Is anything changed in 9.1?

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7733/data-extender-columns-for-only-components-and-pages

Comment: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20924/adding-new-column-to-user-management, try something like might have 'faked' TCM id

Comment: I have tried this too but it is not going to my mycustomlistitems xml. it is always fetching the XML from \tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\ListItems.xml. Is there anything else to be done to redirect to my custom xml? @Velmurugan