# Adding new column to User Management

Tags: gui-extensions, content-manager

I have a DataExtender and a GUI ext that's defining a new column to be added to the DashboardView.
What I can't figure out is how to only add this column into the User Management view?

Looking at [Add listDefinition/Columns only to specific folder](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/add-listdefinition-columns-only-to-specific-folder) would suggest I can target a list definition, but the User Management view doesn't have a TCM ID and "usermng" didn't work ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User Management has a 'faked' TCM id which is "cme:usrmng" (not usermng, as you mentioned)

Have you tried this: idmatch="^cme:usrmng$" ?

```
<extensions>
  <ext:editorextensions>
    <ext:editorextension target="CME">
      <ext:listdefinitions>
        <view name="DashboardView">
          <control id="FilteredItemsList">
            <listdefinition idmatch="^cme:usrmng$" url="%path_to_your_listdefinition_xml%" />
          </control>
        </view>
      </ext:listdefinition>
    </ext:editorextension>
  </ext:editorextensions>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sergii.

Comment: Cool, "welcome" Sergii, to Tridion Stack Exchange. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @AlvinReyes ! This is a very "nostalgic" place :D